Cuncurrency, mutex, semaphores on django and a cron job
I want to create a critical section in django provide controlled section.
One of this is in one of the django channels consumers handling the websocket connections and the other is in a cron process implemented with cron tab, not celery.
I would like these both critical sections to have a lock.
How would I implement this in django.
I know there is python Value,Semaphores, Mutexs but I can not pass the Value to cron job. So Can I use some sort of a file lock. Maybe interprocess communication lock, if that exists.
Anythoughs on how to archive this in Django
